# how to send email using mailgun php code

Tags: email, mailgun

I want to send Email with the help of mailgun using php script. I have already made my account on mailgun site and added my domain and verified my domain. I also have my domain and api key with me .. but how to use these in the php script code

Where to get this vendor/autoload.php I am not able to find it on gihub which is shown in liberary page of mailgun website. I am new to MailGun and I have a hosted site and wanted to use the mailgun for my email sending thru PHP script code, but I am not understanding how to send it. The example code shown in mailgun site tells that start code from vendor/autoload.php and then use mailgun\mailgun and i am not understanding how to get these files and where to copy them. I have already made my account on mailgun site and added and verified my domain and i also have my domain and api key.. but how to use these in the php script code/

Can you please help me how to start and where to get all these files, pleas help? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The vendor/autoload.php can be added by running composer, all info is on the mailgun website https://documentation.mailgun.com/libraries.html#php